# how to test consumers that have filters (Masstransit)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, masstransit

I am trying to test a consumer that is configured with a filter. I would like to know how to unit test for them.

I already use InMemoryTestHarness to do my tests.

I would also like to know if/how it is possible to do the tests using the same configuration that the application uses and not to make a new configuration using InMemoryTestHarness.

My Masstransit configure:

```cs
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue", ep =>
       {
          ep.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(MyFilterConsumer<>), provider);
          ep.ConfigureConsumer<MyConsumer>(provider);
       });
```

My unit test configure:

```cs
public class ConsumerUnitTests : IDisposable
{
   private readonly ServiceProvider _provider;
   private readonly InMemoryTestHarness _harness;

   public ConsumerUnitTests()
   {
      _provider = new ServiceCollection()
         .AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(cfg =>
         {
            cfg.AddConsumer<AssetEventUpdatedConsumer>();
            cfg.AddConsumerTestHarness<AssetEventUpdatedConsumer>();
         })
         .BuildServiceProvider(true);
      _harness = _provider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();
      _ = _harness.Start();
   }
```

with these settings I can test consumers normally. I would like to know how to test with the filter (as specified in the MassTransit configuration)

Comment: Can you explain more detail about how to test a customer that is configured with a filter? Query the database? About using unit test in asp.net core, you can refer the following tutorial: [Unit test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [Unit Testing With xUnit And Moq In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/unit-testing-with-xunit-and-moq-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: I think I didn't explain it right. I know how to do unit tests. What I need to know is how to test a consumer (MassTransit) that has a message filter. I edited the question with an example

Answer (score 0):

```cs
_harness.OnConfigureInMemoryBus += (cfg) =>
{
    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(YourFilter<>), _provider.GetService<IConfigurationServiceProvider>());
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.